# Plotting Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

this is my first question on the forum.

I am using Pandas to read a .dta database. In this database, I have the answers to a survey carried out in different years. In this case 2011-2012-2013-2014.

What I want to do is a horizontal bar chart with the crossing of two variables, but that the result for each year is seen in the same chart, instead of making a chart for each of the years that the survey was conducted.

Is this possible to do with Matplotlib?

Thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can plot your graph horizontally by using this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
Copy to clipboard
```

Comment: Hi Amin, thanks for your answer. Where can I find more info about the parameters of function barh?

Comment: Here you can find more in detail information: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Amin, All the best to you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow my friend. As an advice, it would be better you show a piece of your data frame. I created a dummy dataframe like this;

[image]

First, you need to turn your year variable to categorical(just an advice)

```
df["Year"] = df["Year"].astype('category')
```

Then I used this piece of code

```
ax = df.plot(x="Year", y="Var1", kind="bar")
df.plot(x="Year", y="Var2", kind="bar", ax=ax, color="C2")
```

the output is like this

[image]

Comment: Hello sametsokel, thank you for the welcoming to the forum. I just posted an answer with more detail of what I want to do.